# Magento 2.0(Current) to Magento 2.0.2(Latest) Version Upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.4

Today I tried my to upgrade magento 2.0 to latest version but it shows magento 2.0.2(latest) , i think it should be 2.0.4. still if i continue to upgrade for 2.0.2 it shows readiness check fails with number of reasons like :

- Check Cron Scripts
- PHP Version Check
- PHP Settings Check
- PHP Extensions Check
  [image: For refrence sreenshot of error :]

I am using windows 7 ,Xampp and trying toupgrade on my local pc.

Answer (score 1):

Setup Wizard requires specific cron jobs were configured on your server. See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg , in section "Create the cron job" you can see three cron jobs required for Magento application (first one is a regular Magento cron, not needed for the upgrade; and 2nd and 3rd are required for upgrade).
Your readiness check shows that these cron jobs (or one of them) are not setup or not setup correctly. This also leads to other failures (e.g., PHP version). Please, setup your cron jobs correctly and try again.

Comment: is it possible to setup cron job on windows local server ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron for cron alternatives on Windows. Though Magento does not support Windows as OS for the product.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is clearly seen that your PHP version and it's extensions are not compatible. So update that.

Also stop all the Cron which are in action to upgrade your system.